# Need help in learning networking and cryptography apis in java

Tags: java, networking, encryption, network-programming, cryptography

I am a novice Java developer stepping into world of networking. I have read that http is not a secure way of passing data. I want to learn about cryptography, http and https with java. Can you please point me to some  good references and tutorials.

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: You question is not full describe your problem, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Try the book by David (known from the Bouncy Castle provider): http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Cryptography-Java-David-Hook/dp/0764596330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your favorite search-engine and look up references for networking-related technologies

- TCP/IP and Sockets
- HTTP, HTTPS and SSL (and TLS)
- Basic Java networking API:s (java.net.*)
- Cryptography techniques. Symmetric vs Asymmetric algorithms (MD5, DES, AES, RSA etc), one-way (hashing) and two-way encryption
- Java cryptography API (javax.crypto)
- Popular 3d party/open source networking libraries like Apache HttpComponents
- Java and SSL, certificates and signing

Honestly, just wikipedia gets you pretty far as a starting-point.